# When are tests run with yeoman angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner

I generated a small yeoman angularjs project. If I run `grunt serve` it runs the application and loads it to the browser. Each time I change something in a test grunt reruns the test and I can see the result. If I change the script which will be tested, the matching test is NOT executed.

Does anyone know whether I do something wrong, or how I can tell grunt that it should run all tests each time my scripts change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grunt serve` uses `watch` task to watch for file changes. By default `watch` configuration for tests only includes JS files inside "test" folder. To run tests every time JS files inside "scripts" folder are changed you need to add those files to `watch:jsTest` task configuration inside your `Gruntfile.js`. It should look similar to this:

```
watch: {
  ...
  jsTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js', '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
  },
  ...
```